# AWS private API Gateway with Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible on AWS to use Nginx as a reverse proxy before AWS API gateway? This means AWS API gateway should be private, without direct internet access:
Client (internet) -> EC2 with Nginx reverse proxy -> API gateway.

Is this possible? If yes, can anyone direct me to some tutorial/instructions?

Comment: This might help: [Create a private API in Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html)

Comment: Please refer [1] and let me know if you observe any specific errors. I will be able to help on fixing them. While I am not much experienced with Nginx, I believe this cab be done. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html